Frida - Java application freezes after replacement of a method
Can I know the name of the class and method (from the java decompiler) to replace its implementation  or make the JVM call my method instead of the target method? (in runtime)
I tried using frida for this purpose, but the application freezes after replacing.
Env
$ java --version
java 17.0.11 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)
$ frida --version
16.2.5

Script
// I'm trying to replace the StringBuilder constructor implementation in a desktop Java application using frida api

Java.perform(() => {
    
    const StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
    // We need to replace .$init() instead of .$new(), since .$new() = .alloc() + .init()
    const ctor = StringBuilder.$init.overload('java.lang.String');
    ctor.implementation = function (arg) {
        console.log(arg); return this.$init(arg);
    };
    console.log('[+] new StringBuilder(java.lang.String) hooked');

});


I don't think this.ctor(arg) will work because ctor is a variable and not a field/method of this. You can call this.$init(arg) or ctor.call(this, arg).

Thank you! It's a typo in the question, the error didn't go anywhere.
